# Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "[ng:test] no injector found for element argument to getTestability

Tags: angularjs, testing, automation, jasmine, protractor

I'm getting the following error with protractor when I try to switch between a non angular page to angular page setting **browser.ignoreSynchronization = false** in afterEach function.

```
Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "[ng:test] no injector found for element argument to getTestability\nhttp://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/ng/test
```

Does anyone knows what could I do to solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No injector found for element argument to getTestability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28040078/no-injector-found-for-element-argument-to-gettestability)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `browser.driver.get` instead of `browser.get`.